# Single word for "go in vain"

Tags: single-word-requests

Consider this example sentence:

> His efforts will **go in vain**.

I want to make this sentence precis while adding a single verb, such as:

> His efforts have been ______ .

Can I include the verb waste or spoil in place of go in vain? like this:

> His efforts have been wasted/spoiled.

Comment: Idiomatically, it's *His efforts will **be** in vain.* In principle you could just use ***vain*** adjectivally, as *His efforts were vain*, since we can certainly refer to [*his vain attempts to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+vain+attempts+to%22) *[do something, which efforts were unsuccessful.]* But that might get confused with ***vanity***. Poetically, *His efforts have been **as** naught* (though in practice, [*His efforts have been **for** naught*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22efforts+have+been+for+naught%22) is more common).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Wasted*** is the correct option for your sentence as written:

> His efforts have been *wasted*.

The verb waste means (among other things):

> ***[waste](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/waste)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> 1. *[with object]* Use or expend carelessly, extravagantly, or to no purpose.
>
>    *‘we can't afford to waste electricity’*
>    *‘I don't use the car, so why should I waste precious money on it?’*

(From the Oxford Living Dictionaries)

***Spoiled***, on the other hand, would not be appropriate, as it means to go bad, to be lessened in value or quality:

> ***[spoil](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/spoil)***
>
> **VERB**
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Diminish or destroy the value or quality of.
>
>    *‘I wouldn't want to spoil your fun’*
>    *‘a series of political blunders spoilt their chances of being re-elected’*

(From the Oxford Living Dictionaries)

The efforts haven't been spoiled (made bad) just wasted.

As @FumbleFingers pointed out, *his efforts could have been **in vain*** or they could *have been **for naught***.

Answer (score 2):

In a comment, FumbleFingers wrote:

> Idiomatically, it's *His efforts will **be** in vain.* In principle you could just use ***vain*** adjectivally, as *His efforts were vain*, since we can certainly refer to [*his vain attempts to*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22his+vain+attempts+to%22) *[do something, which efforts were unsuccessful.]* But that might get confused with ***vanity***. Poetically, *His efforts have been **as** naught* (though in practice, [*His efforts have been **for** naught*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22efforts+have+been+for+naught%22) is more common).

Answer (score -3):

His effort will be pointless/ futile/worthless
From oxford dictionary of english

Comment: The request is for a past-tense verb to complete the sentence 'His efforts have been ______.'  A good answer also includes explanation, context, and supporting facts that show why the answer is correct.